# Default solution name is project name for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed the Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and when I create a new project for example Window Desktop Wizard even if I set on "Name" label "Project_name" and on "Solution" label "Solution_name" the solution name is automatically set as "Project_name".

[image]
[image]

In the previous version of Visual Studio (2013, 2015) this behavior does not happen.

Do you know if this behavior is standard starting with VS 2017?

Comment: This was all recently changed.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about it.  And be sure to keep it updated, new releases come fast and furious.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. @HansPassant